# ngClass or class="{{}}"?

Tags: angular, ng-class

Just curious if there are any bigger advantages on any of these approaches?

```
  <div class="small" ngClass="well-{{small}}">small</div>
```

or

```
  <div class="small" class="well-{{big}}">big</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are using `ngClass` it does not matter. Although, ngClass allows us to conditionally add classes, i.e.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

when using `class`, you will have something like:

```
<some-element [class]="someExpression ? 'first' : ''">...</some-element>
```

To sum it up, ngClass is more flexible when you have to add conditional classes.

Answer (score 3):

*If you want to add `class`, use `class` as below.

```
class="className"
```

*If you want to add one `class` conditionally, you can use `class/ngClass in angular` as below.

```
[class.className]="condition"  
[ngClass]="{'className': condition}"
```

*If you want to add more than one `class` conditionally, you have two way.

`Way 1:` Use `class in angular` as below:

```
[class.className1]="condition1"  
[class.className2]="condition2"
.
.
.
```

`Way 2:` Use `ngClass in angular` as below:

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': condition1 , 'class2': condition2 ... }"
```

And clearly the 2nd way is better than the 1st. Phew !!

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage in my experience is when you want to format the data.
For example a date, otherwise it is the same:

```
{{'1288323623006' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
```